# "'CCLayer' may not respond to ... "

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

Playing with cocos2d and this seems to come up in some instances of message passing. I have to admit, I'm not well versed in Objective-C yet as I'm reading through the book as I write some code.

For people familiar with cocos2d, you have a `CCLayer` class. In my case, I have a `GameLayer` which has some children layers, like so:

```
@interface GameLayer : CCLayer {  
  CCSprite *_background;
  CCPanZoomController *_controller;    
  CCLayer *_truckLayer;
}
```

I then have a special `initWithLayers` method to add my child layers within this layer:

```
-(id)initWithLayers:(TruckLayer *)truck
{
if( (self=[super init])) {
    self.truckLayer = truck;
    .....
}
```

Now if I ever send a message to `self.truckLayer` I get the following warning in Xcode:

```
'CCLayer' may not respond to 'getNextAvailableSpot'
```

An example might be doing something like so:

```
CGPoint nextSpot = [self.truckLayer getNextAvailbleSpot];
```

All this code compiles and runs successfully, so I'm curious as to what I am missing here? I don't want my code literred with these if I'm doing something wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because your declare `*_truckLayer` as `CCLayer`, but on your `init` you assign `(TruckLayer *)truck` to your `CCLayer* _truckLayer`. So `CCLayer` doesn't know about `getNextAvailableSpot` method, so the compiler gives you warning.

The code runs fine because `_truckLayer` is a pointing to correct `TruckLayer`, which knows about `getNextAvailableSpot`.

Simply change your declaration and the warning will be gone.

```
@interface GameLayer : CCLayer 
{  
    CCSprite *_background;
    CCPanZoomController *_controller;    
    CCLayer *_truckLayer;
}
```

to

```
@class TruckLayer;
@interface GameLayer : CCLayer 
{  
    CCSprite *_background;
    CCPanZoomController *_controller;    
    TruckLayer *_truckLayer;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just as the warning says: the compiler can't guarantee that CCLayer has a method to handle the getNextAvailableSpot message.  Unless you've somehow added in such a method dynamically, or have some other (very good) reason to believe that this method is present, this is probably a problem.

Comment: The method exists within the TruckLayer class as well as its header file

Comment: Is TruckLayer a subclass of CCLayer?  That might be the problem, then: truckLayer is declared a CCLayer, which (I'd guess) does NOT have this method.